# Amazon EC2 instance free tier but there's bill charges. Can't get any idea where the charges come from

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and just want to try around with the free-tier. Basically, I deployed a Laravel web on EC2 instance. Used Route 53 to route a bought domain (goDaddy) to the EC2 IP. Used the AWS RDS as the database.

I have a python script which I ran manually on computer to regularly input new data into the database through Laravel API

```
url = "http://<Public DNS IP>/api/posts"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = out)
```

I checked my recent billing information and saw 26.108 GB under Asia Pacific (Singapore) > Bandwidth > $0.010 per GB - regional data transfer - in/out/between EC2 AZs or using elastic IPs or ELB

I got no ElasticBeanstalk nor uses elastic IP on my AWS.
There is only one availability of the EC2 instance which is asia-pacific-1a

How is there a 26GB data transfer out of nowhere which cost $0.26 (which is alright) but I am just curious to know.

Thank you

Comment: This question does not belong on stack overflow. This is a question for server fault.

Comment: Assuming you have no load balancer in this solution I would suspect that your instance and the RDS database are in separate availability zones.

Comment: @KurtFriars Could you explain why "This question does not belong on stack overflow"? It would be useful for OP or anyone with similar questions. Thank you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-queue-work/295674#295674, this question is "About professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration".

Comment: Are the machines EC2 and RDS on a public subnet, or are they private. If they are public are you referencing the Public DNS names / IP Addresses or private. If public, traffic will route out of the VPC and back into the VPC causing Egress Traffic Costs (Assuming all your servers are located in the SAME AZ) Best practice move all your servers to a private subnet. All private IPs (EC2 + RDS), and front the webserver and with an ELB which has a public IP

Comment: @KurtFriars I respectful disagree. The `amazon-web-services` tag states "Questions about programming and architecture are on topic". The question in my opinion is about architecture, as the price issue will be caused by OP's architecture. The solution would need to identify component of the OP's architecture on AWS which leads to these charges.

Comment: To me this seems like troubleshooting aws config, and not about programming or code.

Comment: @KurtFriars It does not have to be about programming or code to be on SO.  Its about wrong aws architecture leading to these charges.  `amazon-web-services` tag clearly writes that architecture questions are on topic.

Comment: @Marcin Agree to disagree :) I think this question is much more likely to find answers on Server Fault, and is a better forum for it. And I think that the tag's "architecture" is more about software architecture relating to aws and its services, and not to architecting which servers you have in what AZ etc...

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the replies! I will explore more towards Jason's answer on "Best practice move all your servers to a private subnet. All private IPs (EC2 + RDS), and front the webserver and with an ELB which has a public IP". Yes all my EC2 instance and RDS are in the same AZ thus I was wondering where does the cost come from. Thank you

Comment: @JasonPythonBeginner did you come right with the private VPC architecture?

Comment: @Jason I am still fumbling around different sites and testing the EC2 instances to see what sticks to be honest as AWS is still relatively new to me

Comment: @JasonPythonBeginner in services in the console search for VPC, on the main page press LaunchVPCWizard there is an option for Public Private VPC, it does need an Elastic IP, and it will create a NAT Gateway which costs money, once it is up and running you can delete the NAT gateway and free up the Elastic IP. You only need the NAT if you want your private machines to access the internet. Put the ELB in the public subnet and your EC2 and RDS in the private subnet